# Azure Table string entity

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

On inserting the entity:

```
{
  PartitionKey: { _: 'user@example.com', '$': 'Edm.String' },
  RowKey: { _: 'a31d564b-20bc-4721-8b76-57d124967987', '$': 'Edm.String' },
  filename: { _: 'file-foo', '$': 'Edm.String' }
 }
```

it gets retrieved as:

```
{
  PartitionKey: { '$': 'Edm.String', _: 'user@example.com' },
  RowKey: { '$': 'Edm.String', _: 'a31d564b-20bc-4721-8b76-57d124967987' },
  filename: { _: 'file-foo' },
  Timestamp: { '$': 'Edm.DateTime', _: 2016-07-25T07:31:11.117Z },
  '.metadata':
   { metadata: 'http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/$metadata#UserJobs/@Element',
     etag: 'W/"datetime\'2016-07-25T07%3A31%3A11.117Z\'"' }
}
```

Notice that the retrieved entity's `filename` doesn't have property `'$': 'Edm.String'`

If the `retrieveEntity()`  option `autoResolveProperties` is set, then `filename` gets the property `'$': 'Edm.String'`

However, it would feel safer to avoid the `autoResolveProperties` option since the [documentation](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/TableService.html) mentions `The logic for returning entity types can get complicated`.

The app doesn't need auto detection of properties. It only needs to retrieve  the identical type which is explicitly inserted (`Edm.String`).

Is it possible to do this without setting `autoResolveProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

As the description in the source code of [Azure Storage SDK for node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/tableservice.js#L906),

> The service only provides a type if JsonFullMetadata or JsonMinimalMetadata is used, and if the type is Int64, Guid, Binary, or DateTime.

So the string type should will not be provides by default. However, we can leverage the [`options.propertyResolver`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/tableservice.js#L875) parameter to custom a function to retrieve the edm type.

Please try the following code snippet:

```
var propertyResolver = function (pk, rk, name, value) { 
    if (name.indexOf('BinaryField') !== -1) { 
    return 'Edm.Binary'; 
    } else if (name.indexOf('GuidField') !== -1) { 
    return 'Edm.Guid'; 
    } else if (name.indexOf('DateField') !== -1) { 
    return 'Edm.DateTime'; 
    } else if (name.indexOf('DoubleField') !== -1) { 
    return 'Edm.Double'; 
    } 
    return 'Edm.String'; 
};
var options = {};
options.propertyResolver = propertyResolver; 
tableSvc.retrieveEntity('table', 'user@example.com', 'a31d564b-20bc-4721-8b76-57d124967987',options, function(error, result, response){
  if(!error){
    // result contains the entity
    console.log(result)
  }
});
```

Please refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2014/06/26/microsoft-azure-storage-client-module-for-node-js-v-0-2-0/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks [@Gary Liu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4989668/gary-liu-msft), I tried it out. Technically, it works but also means extra code to handle all properties names - not so maintainable for the source code, don't you think? For now a workaround is to detect `typeof _` whenever `$` is missing and determining if its a string. I guess its similar to doing what `autoResolveProperties` does. Thank you for your response and the links.